# C++ error, compiler won't recognize string::push_back

Tags: c++, string, c++11, compiler-errors

The function it has an issue with:

```
string encode (string message, string key) {

    string code = "whatever";
    string forst;
    int num;
    string::size_type begin = 0;

    message = lower_and_strip(message);

    for (char val : message) {
        num = return_encoded_char(key, begin, val);
        forst = to_string(num);
        code.push_back(forst); //*******************************
    }


    return code;
}
```

The starred line is what it points to. The return_encoded_char function returns an integer.

The specific error is 
`proj05.cpp:68:23: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string<char>::push_back(std::string&)'` and points to the line I starred.

I initially just declared `code` without initializing it, but changing that didn't fix it. All the similar questions I could find had some other element to blame; I feel like this should be relatively straightforward, though obviously it's not since it isn't working.

I have `#include <stream>` and `using std::to_string` etc. I'm using -std=c++11 to compile it.

Help.

P.S. Using Geany on Linux.

Comment: `string` doesn't have a `push_back` member that takes another `string`.

Comment: Use the += operator instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `code` variable is a `std::string`.  The `std::string` class doesn't have a `push_back()` method that takes another `std::string` as input. You should try with the `+=` operator instead, which accepts a character or a string:

```
string encode (string message, string key) {

    string code = "whatever";
    string forst;
    int num;
    string::size_type begin = 0;

    message = lower_and_strip(message);

    for (char val : message) {
        num = return_encoded_char(key, begin, val);
        forst = to_string(num);
        code += forst; //*******************************
    }

    return code; 
}
```

Comment: `std::string` DOES have a [`push_back()` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back), just not one that accepts a `std::string` as input, only a single `char`.

Comment: You are right Remy Lebeau. Thanks for your clarification and for editing the answer. Now it's much better.  :)